# Play video across multiple monitors

Tags: video, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, software-rec

I'm trying to set up a system that plays videos across three large HDTVs. I have the monitors all working, however when I try to maximize the video, it only maximizes on a single screen, rather than all three.

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a [NUC DC53427HYE](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856102035), which has an integrated Intel HD4000 graphics card. I've looked at stuff like Ultramon and DisplayFusion, but none seem to do what I need, which is to maximize a video across all 3 screens without showing the taskbar or anything else.

So, is there any software solution to this? Ideally it would be something that causes the computer to treat all 3 screens as one big screen, so I can simply hit "fullscreen" on whatever media player and it just works, however other solutions would also work as long as it ends up with the video file playing across all 3 screens without anything else showing.

Comment: Can you supply some more information about how the monitors are defined in the "Screen resolution" dialog and whether you can extend the desktop to all three.

Comment: They are set as "extend desktop to this screen" and that works just fine. The problem I'm having is getting a video to play seamlessly across all 3 monitors without the taskbar or anything else showing.

Comment: (1) Are all three monitors identical? (2) Can you manually resize the player across all three monitors? (3) Does setting the taskbar to hide automatically work for all monitors?

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) Yes, (3) Not sure what you mean.

Comment: (2) You mean that you can resize the player to full-desktop but you would rather do that with one press of a button? (3) I mean auto-hide.

Comment: Is the end result you want the same as in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828808/how-can-i-maximize-a-window-across-multiple-monitors)? If not then what is missing?

Comment: That looks like close to what I want, but does it also hide the taskbar and other such things? It's very important that nothing but the video itself shows.

Comment: The AutoHotKey solution is what I had in mind when asking my above question. You haven't answered also if setting the taskbar to [auto-hide](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/auto-hide-taskbar-windows) solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) supports this feature.

Tools > Preferences > Show settings: All > Video > Filters > enable Panoramix.  Then open the Filters tree, go to Panoramix, and choose the settings you want (e.g. 3 columns, 1 row).

Keep in mind, your video would have to be an extremely wide aspect ratio (e.g. 3840x720).  Even an [anamorphic widescreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21:9_aspect_ratio) movie wouldn't quite fill two HDTVs.

Comment: I tried VLC before when I had Linux running, but I couldn't get it to work as I wanted. I'll try again with the windows version and see if it's any better. Resolution isn't a problem, as all 3 screens are turned sideways and the videos will be high enough resolution to cover all 3 screens.

Comment: @AgentPaper I see you left a comment that "there might not be a software solution".  Did this not work for you?  In what way didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you're asking for a software solution but anyway here's what I've found: http://www.datapath.co.uk/products/multi-display-products/datapath-x4

> The Datapath x4 is a stand alone display wall controller that accepts a standard single or dual-link DVI input and can flexibly display this across four output monitors.
>
> Each output can be driven as DVI or analog RGB, and can represent an arbitary crop region of the original input image. The output resolution and frame rate does not need to be related to that of the input, as the Datapath x4 display controller will optionally upscale and frame rate convert each cropped region independently.
>
> Each output monitor can take its input from any region of the DVI image, since all the required cropping, scaling, rotation and frame rate conversion is handled by the x4 hardware.  These regions can overlap to allow any output to replicate another, or they can be configured to support any creative splice of the source material.
>
> This allows the support of many non-rectangular screen arrangements with uneven gaps, and any mix of orientations.

Comment: It seems like there might not be a software solution (which is weird, because it seems like this should be very simple), so I might end up using something like this.

Comment: @AgentPaper There's not a pure software solution to this because it would break 3D acceleration. However, the ability to do what is described in this answer is already built in to most AMD and NVidia graphics cards from the last few years. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said VLC Media Player as well but perhaps Wall might work better for you.

Tools > Video Effects > Geometry > Wall (then rows and columns).

Basically it will slice your video up into pieces, each of which you can maximise to a given screen. Great for big displays, kiosks, retail environments etc. Need monitors with limited bevels tho otherwise it will look awful.

Comment: When I tried this, it created multiple windows for the wall, but each window had the entire video, not a piece of it.

Comment: @Jason If it is not a secret then in what format is the video. If you rather not tell then I would suggest you first try this method with some small common format video - to make sure this doesn't work for other formats as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many NVidia and ATI/AMD graphics cards support this natively. NVidia's feature is called [NVidia Surround](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/surround) and ATI/AMD's is called [AMD Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/eyefinity).

NVidia has a guide on how to set up Surround [here](http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/how-to-correctly-configure-geforce-gtx-680-surround#1).

AMD has a guide on how to set up Eyefinity [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/gpu50-amd-eyefinity-display-groups.aspx).

Both of these essentially present a single frame buffer to the operating system, so the OS thinks that there is just one really huge monitor attached. The graphics driver will then display the correct portion of that frame buffer on each monitor that is part of the setup. Note that this will apply both to games and to your regular desktop. When you maximize anything, it will take up all 3 monitors, as the OS doesn't even know that it's three different displays. It thinks it's just one really wide display.